# Does JSF 2.0 strip out HTML attributes when rendering?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I have to work with existing HTML and CSS and convert it to JSF app. So there are pure `<li>` elements (no JSF tags) with `class=""` attributes. When rendered with JSF 2.0 under Glassfish 3.1.1 the `class=""` attribute is removed from the `<li>` elements and the CSS breaks, i.e. the site breaks.

Probably the setting `class=""` is not the best to do but why does JSF strip it off when it affects the display of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Facelets does only do that for attributes with empty values. It does not do that for attributes with **a** value like `class="some"`. So nothing would break at all (expect of some hypothetically poor JS which rely on the presence of the attribute instead of the presence of an attribute value).

Note that GF 3.1.1 ships with JSF 2.1, not JSF 2.0 (to be precise, Mojarra 2.1.3).

Comment: @Kozmoz: use `<h:selectOneMenu>` instead.

Comment: But still it can be an issue difficult to solve. I'm working on an application where we use JSF mixed with AngularJS. Some parts are JSF and the forms are build with AngularJS. To bootstrap Angular, an empty "ng-app" attribute has to be added to a parent element, but JSF strips these attributes: `<div ng-app=""> </div>`

Comment: so, how would one go about using Angular with JSF effectively?

Comment: `<f:verbatim>` seems to be the perfect solution to this problem. Thnx @gpilotino

Answer (score 1):

use `<f:verbatim>` tag

```
    <f:verbatim>
      <div class="" custom-attribute="x"></div>
    </f:verbatim>
```

this would print content without filtering.